# Polymer: Is it bad to use the <content> tag? (Possible deprecation?)

Tags: html, polymer-1.0

It appears it's getting deprecated. However, it's used in some of Google's Polymer elements anyway

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is bad. The element was part of a planned feature and is not implemented in all browsers. As the page says, in Firefox it has to be turned on separately.

[Can I use...](http://caniuse.com/#search=Shadow%20dom) also shows it's basically a Chrome only thing.

The Polymer web site says

> Polymer 1.0 replaces the shadow DOM polyfill with a lightweight shim

So it provides the functionality for browsers that don't support it. That is why it can use it.